# ESP8266 Returning code 400 on POST request in Django webapp

Tags: django-rest-framework, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I deployed my django webapp to the internet but I can't POST request a data because it's returning
HTTP CODE 400,
`const char* serverName = "https://example.com/api/v1/post_sample";` = returns 400 code.

but when I do: `const char* serverName = "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/post_sample";` it works and return 201 code.

It didn't put any restrictions or auth for now on the web application. I even did a POST request on Postman to the web application I deployed, it also works.

Please help. Thanks!

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

const char* ssid = "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_SSID";
const char* password = "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_PASSWORD";


const char* serverName = "https://example.com/api/v1/post_sample";


unsigned long lastTime = 0;
unsigned long timerDelay = 5000;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("Connecting");
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to WiFi network with IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
 
  Serial.println("Timer set to 5 seconds (timerDelay variable), it will take 5 seconds before publishing the first reading.");
}

void loop() {
  if ((millis() - lastTime) > timerDelay) {
    //Check WiFi connection status
    if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED){
      HTTPClient http;
      
      http.begin(serverName);

      http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      int httpResponseCode = http.POST("{\"value\":\"1\"}");
     
      Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
        
      http.end();
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("WiFi Disconnected");
    }
    lastTime = millis();
  }
}
```

Comment: is example.com is your domain?

Comment: yes, its just an example can't disclose it here because its private.

Answer (score 1):

1. You didn't establish a `WiFiClient` before trying to establish a http connection.
2. For POST request with `ESP8266HTTPClient`, you pass in the url when you establish `http.begin(client, url)` with an established client instance.  See the [example](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient/examples/PostHttpClient/PostHttpClient.ino#L50-L60) code. In your case, it should be:

   ```
   if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED){
      WiFiClient client;
      HTTPClient http;

      http.begin(client, serverName);

      http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      int httpResponseCode = http.POST("{\"value\":\"1\"}");

      Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);

      http.end();
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("WiFi Disconnected");
    }
   ```
3. If you url is an secure connection with `https` as you shown in your example url, then you will need to establish a secure client with a library like `<WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.h>`. See [example](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient/examples/BasicHttpsClient/BasicHttpsClient.ino).

Comment: Hello, I'm getting `HTTP CODE -5` after establishing WiFiClient.

Comment: Add `http.errorToString(httpResponseCode).c_str());` to find out what -5 means.

Comment: Also try to use a public server such as `httpbin.org/post` to test your eps8266 client sketch to make sure it is not your server that causing the problem. Once it works you can then change the url to your own server and do further testing.